# How to show image retreived from firebase in full screen on android 10

Tags: android, image

I am trying to display an image that I retrieved from Firebase storage in full screen.
I have successfully displayed the image in `ImageView`. And also, it works fine on some android phones.
But on android 10, `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/... typ=image/* (has extras) }` error is happening whenever I try to open it in full screen.
Here is my code to display the image in full screen

```
public void showPhoto(Uri photoUri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, photoUri);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(mActivity.getPackageManager()) != null){
        mActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Is android 10 different from the others?
How can I display an image in full screen using ACTION_VIEW in android 10?

Comment: What does this have to do with full screen?

Comment: I have an image view with a small size, so when the image view is clicked, I want to display the image on a full screen using ACTION_VIEW. But it does not work in android 10.

Comment: But what does your problem have to do with full screen?

Comment: I think android 10 does not support ACTION_VIEW for images. That is why I am getting ActivityNotFoundException.